# How to extract seconds from time taken from ntp server

Tags: python, datetime, time, digits, ntp

I was able to get the current time from an NTP server with the following code. Now I tried to get the seconds from the time but it did not work. Can someone please explain how I can take the seconds only from the time.

I tried to convert the time into a list with integers in it and then take the 18th and 19th digit.

```
import ntplib
from datetime import datetime, timezone
c = ntplib.NTPClient()
        # Provide the respective ntp server ip in below function
response = c.request('uk.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
response.offset
        # UTC timezone used here, for working with different timezones you can use [pytz library][1]
currenttime =datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, timezone.utc)
print (currenttime)
d = map(int, str(currenttime))
print (list(d))
```

This is what I got on the console.

```
2019-07-15 20:56:19.952231+00:00

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.second) about accessing elements of `datetime.datetime` objects. As a sidenote: what's the point of converting a timestamp to a _data structure_ representing date & time if you're then converting this _structure_ to an _unstructured_ string?

Comment: ... why not just retrieve it with [`datetime.second`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.second)?

Comment: Thanks guys! I just watched a short tutorial video about datetime object. Now I will read the docs to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the seconds from the `datetime` object you've already created:

```
d = currenttime.second
```

See also: [`datetime.second` - Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.second)